# What is the definition of identity bimodule in the context of von Neumann or $\ast$-algebras?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I will just repeat the question in the title:

What is the definition of identity bimodule in the context of von Neumann or $\ast$-algebras?

I know what a bimodule is but I never heard up to yesterday the term identity bimodule.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the bimodule $_MM_M$ or, if you  consider Hilbert bimodules, $_ML^2(M)_M$.

Comment: One does not need a trace on M to define L^2: the Haagerup standard form is defined for any von Neumann algebra.

Comment: True. $\ \ \ \ $